# Direct2D: Create BitmapRenderTarget without CreateCompatibleRenderTarget

Tags: c++, graphics, bitmap, rendering, direct2d

Is there a way to create a `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget` without calling `CreateCompatibleRenderTarget` on a "parent" render target?

MSDN shows the way how I can do it with WIC, but I am not sure, will the drawing operations be accelerated by GPU, so not sure to go this way.

Thank you.

Comment: While it's true that a WIC bitmap render target will use software rendering, ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget is not related to WIC (don't get confused by both using the term "bitmap") so I'm unsure what's your question really about?

Comment: I need capabilities to render things off screen without window at all, so I am looking for soulution how I can do that

Comment: If you don't need to get back the bitmaps from the GPU (to the CPU) you don't need WIC, CreateCompatibleRenderTarget allows you to use off screen bitmaps (ID2D1Bitmap).

Comment: CreateCompatibleRenderTarget implies I need another render target, usually it's HwndRenderTarget, but I don't have it

Comment: Of course to create a compatible render target, you need a render target. The only primary render targets you can create are 1) a DXGI surface, 2) an HDC, 3) an HWND, 4) a direct composition visual, or 5) a WIC bitmap. If you cannot create 1 to 4 then you have to use a WIC bitmap. If you do have a graphic card, but don't want to use HDC or HWND, use a DXGI surface, otherwise WIC is fine (but it's a software tech)

Comment: DXGI Surface, ok! Thank you for your detailed comment.